# How can i add an existing visual studio 2019 project to a git repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a boilerplate project named 'XYZ' structured like this:

```
-XYZ.Domain
-XYZ.CrossCutting
-XYZ.Application
-XYZ.Backend
-XYZ.Infrastructure
```

I want to do these steps:

1. Rename everything to ABC:

   ```
   -ABC.Domain
   -ABC.CrossCutting
   -ABC.Application
   -ABC.Backend
   -ABC.Infrastructure
   ```
2. Add it to a git repository
3. Push everything.

How can I accomplish this using visual studio 2019?

Comment: push everything assumes that a git repository exists, and is added as remote of the repository you are adding these files to. Are we on the same ground here?

Answer (score 0):

From the solution explorer select your solution and pick Create Git Repository (requires the new Git Tools to be enabled):

[image]

Fill in the wizard that pops up:

[image]

And you have a reporitory. If you don't have a `.gitignore` file yet, I'd pick "local repo", as using one of the other options will immediately commit & push. Then add the ignore file and exclude any items you don't wish to push before pushing to a git service:

[image]

You can do your renames before or after. Which would be a separate and unrelated question to how to initialize the git repo.

Renaming the project files can easily be done in the solution explorer. Renaming the folder containing each project is trickier. You need:

- Rename the project in Solution explorer
- Save all files <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
- Remove the renamed project from your solution
- Rename the project folder in Windows Explorer.
- Use the <kbd>Add existing project</kbd> option in the solution explorer to add the project file in its new location:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It's cleaner to re-name prior to adding a Git repo, but it can be done after.
2. To push to a Git service *without* additional tools simply create a local repo by right-clicking your solution and select Create Git Repository.  Next, in Team Explorer click the sync option...
   [image]

Then, it will ask you to Push to a Git service.
[image]

Follow the prompts to sign in to the service of your choice and choose the project/repo.